# Trying to save with model formset factory getting 'list' object has no attribute 'event'

Tags: python, django, formset

I'm trying to save a related model field via Django `model_formset` but it's giving me this error:

```
AttributeError at /events/event/52/detail
'list' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Has anyone ever encountered this, and knows how to solve it? Thanks.

**View**

```
def event_detail(request, pk):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk)
    TicketFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ticket,
                                         exclude=('event',),
                                         extra=1, max_num=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ticket_form = TicketFormSet(request.POST)
        if ticket_form.is_valid():
            ticket_obj = ticket_form.save(commit=False)
            ticket_obj.event = event
            ticket_obj.save()
    else:
        ticket_form = TicketFormSet()
    return render(request, 'events/event/event_detail.html',
              {'event': event, 'formset': ticket_form})
```

**Model**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.event.name, self.name)
```

Comment: How are you defining your forms? Please update the question with relevant part of `forms.py`

Comment: @drec4s it has nothing to do with the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formset creates a *list* of objects, so `ticket_form` is a list, not a model instance. You would need to set `event` on each item in the list.

But you should be using an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), which will do this automatically:

```
TicketFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Event, Ticket,
                                      exclude=('event',),
                                      extra=1, max_num=3)
if request.method == 'POST':
    ticket_form = TicketFormSet(request.POST, instance=event)
    if ticket_form.is_valid():
        ticket_form.save()
```

Comment: I got this error when I included an instance __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: As I showed, you need to use inlineformset_factory.

Comment: used inlineformset_factory as you advised works like a charm.